# React performance: developing recursive component JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I have developed a react component

1. where JSON is array of object and each object could have another array which is same as parent array as prop. It can go till any depth.
2. I have used a recursive component to render each component and  by calling the same function recursive if the object has anychild/childs
3. One of the specific requirement is whenever a node has to be checked/unchecked its Parent need to notified and Parent will change if all of its child are checked.

JSON data

```
[ 
    {
       name: "name",
       checked: false
       children: [{
         name: "name",
         checked: false
        }]    
    },
    {
       name: "name"
       checked: false,
       children: [{
         name: "name",
         checked: false,
         children: [{
             name: "name",
             checked: false
         },{
             name: "name",
             checked: false
         }]    
      },
      {
         name: "name",
         checked: false
      }]    
    },
    .....
]
```

App.jsx

```
const root = (JSONdata) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(JSONdata)
    const updateData = (nodeToUpdate, positionOfNode) {
        //newData is different referance return by updateNodeAtSpeifiedDeepPosition function as we don't want to mutate data  set in state
        const newData = updateNodeAtSpeifiedDeepPosition(data, nodeToUpdate, positionOfNode);
        setData[newData]
    }
    return ( 
         <Tree data={JSONdata} updateData={updateData} />
    )
}
```

Tree.jsx

```
const Tree = (data) => {
    const [treeNode, setTreeNode] = useEffect(data)
    const renderTree = (nodes) => {
        <li onClick = { updateData) >
            If(treeNode.child) {
                <Tree data = {treeNode.child} />

            } </li>
    }

    return ( <ol >renderTree(treeNode) </ol>
    )
}
```

Its working but on each check or uncheck root is updated and all child are again re rendering as they have new reference.

Is there way to performance optimise it ?

Comment: Not a solution, but it should be `children` not `child` as there can be more than one.

Comment: Yes, use the `key` prop on `li`. The `key` property will allow React to track which list elements have changed and need updating instead of updating all the elements in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation looks fine

On every checkbox change yes of course it will change your root data and it will rerender all the child components

But you can control re-renders of child components using React.memo

Using memo will cause React to skip rendering a component if its props have not changed.

This can improve performance.
Check this for the detailed explanation

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_memo.asp

Please note: react useMemo and react memo are not same;

Comment: Yeh I had implemented the memo key and react callback. But actual issue is where should we define function to propagate event to parent and child (check above 3rd bullet point).

Comment: You are using redux rt?. store your data in redux store and use it in your parent component, and on checked/uncheck event trigger an action to modify the original data in redux. this will update particular child component

Answer (score 0):

Alongside, using the key prop on li elements. You can also wrap your Tree component within React.memo(), this creates a higher order component, which prevents unnecessary re-renders, if the props passed to it have not changed.

After wrapping it within React.memo(), your tree component should look like this:

```
    const Tree = React.memo((data) => {
    const [treeNode, setTreeNode] = useEffect(data)
    const renderTree = (nodes) => {
        <li onClick = { updateData) >
            If(treeNode.child) {
                <Tree data = {treeNode.child} />

            } </li>
    }

    return ( <ol >renderTree(treeNode) </ol>
    )
});
```

This [blog post](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-memo-vs-usememo/) might help more, in understanding the concept.

To fulfill your third requirement, I need to know, what will be the value of `positionOfNode`, within `updateData` function.

```
 const updateData = (nodeToUpdate, positionOfNode) {
    const newData = updateNodeAtSpeifiedDeepPosition(data, nodeToUpdate, positionOfNode);
    setData[newData]
}
```

My suggestion is since your data is an array of JSON objects, let's use array indices to our advantage, provided that the order of elements doesn't change within the array. Assuming that, the position of a node can be defined as a concatenated string of indices. Consider the following data:

```
[ 
{
   name: "name1",
   checked: false
   children: [{
     name: "name2",
     checked: false
    }]    
},
{
   name: "name3"
   checked: false,
   children: [{
     name: "name4",
     checked: false,
     children: [{
         name: "name5",
         checked: false
     },{
         name: "name6",
         checked: false
     }]    
  }];
```

For the node named `name1`, its position should be `0`.
For the node name `name2`, its position should be its parent position + its index in the children array, hence `00`.
Similarly, the position of `name3` will be `1`.
Similarly, the position of `name4` will be `10`.
Similarly, the position of `name5` will be `100`.
Similarly, the position of `name6` will be `101`.

Using these positions in the `updateData` function, the  `updateNodeAtSpeifiedDeepPosition` can be written to notify the parent of a node as well, since its index is already present in the position string.

Comment: How you are planning to achieve above 3 bullet point. Defining function with recursive function ? Where child will trigger function of parent to change ?

Comment: Please check, if my updated answer helps you in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with your state management, so I don't know if my suggestion is applicable.

but if you hold only ids in the tree structure, and alongside it, a map id -> Node. Plus the parent will pass only the id to the children and each child will get its data (name, checked) from somewhere else (there are multiple options here) then the parent is rendered once.

`React.memo` is easier, though the memorization has its cost

Comment: just noticed there is a redux tag on your question, if you are using redux it is rather simple

Comment: There is no redux. But if you share that approach too @alissa

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by "if you share that approach too" can you please clarify?
if you mean for me to make an example, then I need more information :) like by "Parent will change if all of its child are checked" do you mean all descendants or only direct children? and where is the state?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently whenever we do update in parent and update it checked status child will be rerender.